# How can I bind snippet function to onclick event from button or image?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, lift

I have defined this function to build a list os students, each one with his name, surname and an image, that depending an attribute can be a tick or a cross. I want to assign to the tag academic(my image) the onClick event to call a function in my snippet called academic(Student s) which receives a student,and then redirect to another page. Can anyone help me??

```
def students(xhtml: NodeSeq) = {

    def bindStudents(template: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {

      studentsList.flatMap {
        s => bind("studentTag", template, "name" -> s.Name, "surname" -> s.Surname,
          AttrBindParam("academic", if (s.HasIssue("Academic")) tickUrl else crossUrl, "src"),         
        )}
    }
    bind("list", xhtml, "studentsList" -> bindStudents _)
  }


 def academic(s:Student)={
    //do some stuff with s
    redirectTo("/OtherPage.html")
  }
```

HTML CODE

```
<list:studentsList>
            <tr>
                <td> <studentTag:name /> </td>
                <td> <studentTag:surname /> </td>
                <td>
                     <img  studentTag:academic=""/>
                </td>
</list:studentsList>
```

Comment: @Brian Hsu
Thank u for ur answer Brian
Now i try this but it doesnt work
     
<lift:mySnippet2.students>  
    <tr id="tabla">
                <td>
                     <img    width="20" height="20" alt="Computer Hope" id="buttonAcademic" class="clickable"/> </td>

And this in my snippet...

    def students(xhtml: NodeSeq):NodeSeq = {("#tabla" #> studentsList.map { s =>
          "#buttonAcademic [src]" #> (tickUrl) &
          "#buttonAcademic [onClick]" #> SHtml.onEvent(onClickCallback(s)_)}).apply(xhtml)
}

I also try using this but it doesnt work

    ".clickable [onClick]" #>

Comment: Maybe you missing the jQuery lib? Lift do this ajax call by jQuery, so you will need it. Here is a full working example (https://gist.github.com/3548101). You should get a console message and a browser dialog showing the user you choose when you click on avatar icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method in SHtml called '[onEvent](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/net/liftweb/http/SHtml$.html)'.

I'm not very sure how to do this in the old way, but if you are using new [designer-friendly CSS binding helpers](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-7.10.html#toc-Section-7.10), it will be very simple:

HTML template:

```
<div data-lift="MySnippet">
    Name:<span id="name">Student Name</span>
    SurName:<div class="surname">Surname</span>
    <img src="imageURL" class="clickable"/>
</div>
```

Here is the snippet:

```
class MySnippet
{
    val studentName = "whatever"
    val surName = "..."

    def onClickCallback(s: String): JsCmd = {
        // Do what ever you want, BTW, I never have idea
        // what the ``s`` the lift will passed in.

        Alert('Hey, you clicked me.') // This is the javascript that browser will execute when user click on the element.
    }

    // Note there is no argument list
    def render = {
        "#name" #> studentName & // Replace the HTML tag with id="name" to studentName 
        ".surname" #> surName & // Replace the HTML tag with class=surname to surName 
        ".clickable [onClick]" #> SHtml.onEvent(onClickCallback) // Append onClick attribute to HTML tag that has "clickable" class, and it will calle onClickCallable in your snippet.
    }
}
```

## Update

Sorry, I didn't notice that you are binding to a list. But since there is curried function, it would not be too difficult either.

HTML code:

```
<table data-lift="MySnippet">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="name">Name</span></td>
    <td><span class="surname">SurName</span></td>
    <td><img src="test.jpg"/> </td>
  </tr>
</talbe>

case class Student(name: String, surname: String)

class MySnippet
{
    def onClickCallback(student: Student)(s: String): JsCmd = {
        Alert("You Click:" + student)
    }

    val xs = Student("Brian", "Hsu") :: Student("David", "Walter") :: Nil

    def render = {
        "tr" #> xs.map { student => 
            ".name" #> student.name &
            ".surname" #> student.surname &
            ".clickable [onClick]" #> SHtml.onEvent(onClickCallback(student)_) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I correct the ".clickable [onClick]" to ".clickable [onclick]" but it still dont work, I click in my image and nothing happen...do u know why???
Thanks for your quick response @Brian Hsu